# Can we override the functionality of Visual Studio Code's Source Control via extension activation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I went through [Source Control API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/scm-provider#source-control-model) but couldn't find what I needed.
The closest thing I found was to create another source control.

I want to create a tool that extends the git functionality which I already have in the SHELL script. It requires overriding the inner functionality of Source Control itself via an extension activation. Do you think they allow it?